# Cargar listado en div con botón, php y ajax

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

La idea es cargar un listado al darle a un botón de los del menú (de momento solo Animal), el listado en si me funciona porque lo he probado a aparte, es decir que directamente me haga el listado y va genial; el problema lo tengo al tener que hacer este listado tras pulsar un botón y que aparezca en un div.

He tenido dos problemas, uno es que funcionaba pero pocho, me cargaba solo 3 resultados, la pagina 2 no funcionaba y me duplicaba el listado; el otro problema es este error:

> POST
> http://localhost/DWES/PeriodoRepaso/RecuTema3SergioCervera/ModelAnimal/paginacionInicial.php
> 404 (Not Found)            jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4.

Ni siquiera se a que se refiere ese error.
Mi código es el siguiente
El menú Inicial donde tengo el botón.(Se carga la vista desde el index)

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        
        <style>
            nav{
                padding-top: 20px;
                padding-left: 20px;
            }
            button{
                background: lightgrey;
                padding: 10px;
                font-size: 14px;
                border: 0.5px solid black;
                border-radius: 5px;
                box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 45px rgba(100,100,100,0.2), 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
                transition: box-shadow 1s ease; 
            }
            a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
            }
            a:visited{
                color:blue;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="formulario">
        <nav>
            <button id="btnAnimales">Animales</button>
            <button id="btnUsuarios">Usuarios</button>
            <button id="btnAdopciones">Adopciones</button>
        </nav>
        </form>
        <div id="opciones"></div>
    </body>
    <script>
            
            $('#btnAnimales').click(function(e)
              {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  $.ajax({
                      url: 'ListadoAnimales.php',
                      type: 'post',
                      data: $('#formulario').serialize(),
                      success: function(res)
                      {
                          $('#opciones').html(res);
                      }
                  });
              });
    </script>
</html>
```

Luego tengo la paginacion(El modelo):

```
    <?php 

$servidor="localhost";
$usuario="root";
$clave="";
$bd="protectora_animales";


try {
    $conn= new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=$bd", $usuario, $clave);
             
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo "Error: " .$ex->getMessage();
    die();
}


//Si existe pagina obtenemos el valor entero sino es 1
$pagina = isset($_GET['pagina']) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;

$postPorPagina = 3;

//Si pagina es mayor a 1 obtenemos el numero desde el que se empieza en la pagina que estemos.
$inicio = ($pagina > 1) ? ($pagina * $postPorPagina - $postPorPagina) : 0;

$articulos = $conn->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM animal limit $inicio, $postPorPagina");

$articulos->execute();
$articulos = $articulos->fetchAll();

if(!$articulos)
{
    include "../View/MenuInicial.php";
}

$totalArticulos = $conn->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total");
$totalArticulos = $totalArticulos->fetch()['total'];

$numeroPaginas = ceil($totalArticulos/ $postPorPagina);
        
require '../View/ListadoAnimales.php';
?>
```

Y luego está ya el propio Listado(Esta en Vista):

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Paginacion</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    </head>
    <style>
        *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background: #e9e9e9;
    color: #2e2e2e;
    font-family: Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.contenedor{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}

h1{
    margin: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Oswald", Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #ce7f08;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.contenedor .articulos{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.contenedor .articulos ul{
    list-style: none;
}

.contenedor .articulos ul li{
    padding: 15px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
}

.paginacion ul{
    list-style: none;
}

.paginacion ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.paginacion ul .active a{
    background: #ce7f08;
}

.paginacion ul .disabled{
    background: #c8c8c8;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Oswald", Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.paginacion ul li a{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Oswald", Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    background: #424242;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.paginacion ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #3299bb;
}


    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="contenedor">
            <section class="articulos">
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($articulos as $articulo): ?>
                    <li><?php echo $articulo['id'] . " - " . $articulo['nombre']. " - " . $articulo['especie'] . " - " . $articulo['raza']. " - " . $articulo['genero']
                            . " - " . $articulo['color'] . " - " . $articulo['edad']?></li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </section>
            
            <section class="paginacion">
                <ul>
                    <!-- Establecemos cuando se desactiva el boton de anterior -->
                    <?php if($pagina == 1): ?>
                    <li class="disabled">&laquo;</li>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina - 1 ?>">&laquo;</a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    
                    
                    <!-- Ciclo para mostrar las paginas -->
                    <?php
                    for($i=1;$i<=$numeroPaginas;$i++)
                    {
                        if($pagina == $i)
                        {
                            echo "<li class='active'><a href='?pagina=$i'>$i</a></li>";
                        }else{
                            echo "<li><a href='?pagina=$i'>$i</a></li>";
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    
                    <!-- Establecemos cuando se desactiva el boton de posterior -->
                    <?php if($pagina == $numeroPaginas): ?>
                    <li class="disabled">&raquo;</li>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina + 1 ?>">&raquo;</a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    
                    
                </ul>
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: el error dice que la URL a la que le haces post tiene un error 404, que significa que no se ha encontrado esa url/archivo

Comment: Si era eso, un problema en esa ruta, añadí un index al programa e hice las rutas desde ese index y salió bien, gracias Francisco